# How to add or subtract time from existing cron expressions in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, cron

I have a list of corn expressions (parse-cron v0.1.3).  I am trying to create a function that allows a  user to increment them insofar as they can add an hour, 15 minutes, etc. I was looking at [croniter](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/) and [python-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/), but it appears  I would have to either parse these as strings or potentially convert them to human-readable times, add the time to those, and convert them back to the cron expressions.

Does anyone know if there is a pre-built way to do this or should I just manually create a function to contain all the logic?

Example expressions

```
0 6 * * *
0 6 * * 1-1
*/10 6-9 * * *
*/5 12-13 * * *
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding an hour would be something like going from `0 15 * * *` to `0 16 * * *`? Can you post a few examples of expressions, and the manipulations you want to make on them?

Comment: 0 6 * * *;
0 6 * * 1-1;
*/10  6-9 * * *

Thanks for the response! I can definitely manually update them, but  I was hoping for something a bit more programmatic to not have to worry about as many edge cases.

Comment: What would be the result of adding, say, 15 minutes, to the expression `*/10 6-9 * * *`?